# Show/Hide DIV Chrome Extension

Tags: html, google-chrome-extension, hide, show

What I'm trying to achieve is simple.

Now there's an extension already made called [Note Anywhere](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bohahkiiknkelflnjjlipnaeapefmjbh). Notice when you click the app's icon the sticky note displays on the webpage, and you're able to drag, and drop that div anywhere you want.

What I'm trying to achieve is very similar.

- Click #1 fades div in
- Click #2 fades div out

I'll worry about drag and drop once I can get the div to actually show. I've spent over 16 hours trying to achieve this effect, and after getting extremely agitated I had to edit my question, and ask once more with updated info. So this will no longer be a problem again.

Here's my code.

**Manifest**:

```
{
    "name": "CamDesk",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "description": "The Desktop Webcam Widget",
    "permissions": ["tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
    "background_page": "background.html",

   "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": "images/logo.png",
      "default_title": "CamDesk"
   },

   "content_scripts": [ {
      "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
      "css": ["css/style.css"],
      "js": ["js/jquery.js", "js/jquery-swfobject.js", "js/background.js"]
   } ],

   "icons": {
      "48": "images/48x48.png",
      "256": "images/logo.png"
   }
}
```

**CSS**:

```
.camdesk {
    display:none;
    width:320px;
    height:240px;
    background-color:#FFF;
    box-shadow:0px 4px 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    overflow:hidden;}
```

**Background Page**:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="js/background.js"></script>
</head>
    <div id="camdesk">
        Please install the most recent version of flash to use CamDesk.
    </div>
</html>
```

**Content Script**: *"To Show & Hide DIV"*

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.camdesk').flash({
        swf: './camdesk.swf',
        width: 320,
        height: 240
    });
});

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(getMessage);
getMessage();

function getMessage() {
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
        chrome.tabs.sendRequest(null, function(tab) {
            $('.camdesk').fadeOut(350);
        }); //getting response from content script
    });
}

chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(
  function(sendResponse) {
    if $('.camdesk').fadeIn(350);
      $('.camdesk').fadeOut(350);
    else
      sendResponse({}); 
  });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To create that effect, you need to use [Content Scripts](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html). That is the only way you can manipulate the DOM for a website your visiting. Since your coming from the extension context (Browser Action button), you need to use [Message Passing](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html) to transfer commands to show/hide to the DOM.

So the steps to achieve what you need:

1. Instantiate a [chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/browserAction.html#event-onClicked) in the [Background Page](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/background_pages.html)
2. Use [chrome.tabs.sendRequest](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-sendRequest) to tell the DOM what to do. You need to send a message asking it to Show or Hide the overlay you wanted.
3. Listen on extension requests from the Content Script using [chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html#simple) When you receive a Show or Hide command from the extension, you can add/remove the DOM.

Hope that gives you a slight push!

Comment: I still seem to be having the problem that the div won't show. I posted my code above. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are misunderstanding background pages. Background pages is just a long running script that manages a task or a state. It doesn't implement any view. You need to inject another custom content script that amends your DOM with that div. Then you can either use "chrome.tabs.sendRequest" or "chrome.tabs.executeScript". If you use the latter, then you can execute code `chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {code: 'toggleDiv()'})` Then your context script will contain methods that allow you to toggle.

Comment: This is one of those answers where it's too bad I only have one upvote - thank you.  Also `chrome.tabs.sendRequest` is deprecated; `sendMessage` (https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-sendMessage) is recommended.